# What is this ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS loading error?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, firefox, microsoft-edge

I got this error doin't not anything special.

GET http://localhost:8080/ROOT/css/bootstrap/error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
GET http://localhost:8080/ROOT/css/error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
GET http://localhost:8080/ROOT/css/font/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[image]

What is this error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", I always works this way and never had problems...

Thank you

Comment: Which kind of browser will show this issue? Try to use different browser to check it. Besides, try to clear the browser  data (cookie, cache and history and so on) and check redirects on your application and server. And, can you post the enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I tried to do it but no results. The fact is that I did not change anything in my code and it worked well since now

Comment: After all, you were wright. I just have to be more patient that's all... Thank you @Zhi Lv

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem got back. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Try to run your website in the browser InPrivate/Incognito window. Or restart the browser and check it.

Comment: I found the issue, I had a Servlet with the path "/" which was reponsible of the error...

Comment: I delete it and it worked

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you could organize an answer and post it, then, mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, or when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding. ^_^

Comment: Thank you, I can't validate myself, but may be you can do it. ^^. I have to wait for 2 days otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I had a Servlet with the path "/" which was reponsible of the error..